# add indexing with array element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I have a list of array which contains value in specific pattern.

Each array item need to have a index which is based on the vlaue alongwith.

Initially I though I can do it just dividing it to 500 but that did not work.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfwwt9py/)

```
var get = [500,0,4000,1000]
var str = ""
get.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item / 500)
});

Output should be like 
1_0,
2_500,
3_1000,
5_4000,
```

Edit: If array would have value `2000` then output look like

```
1_0,
2_500,
3_1000,
4_2000,
5_4000,
```

Comment: Based on the output it just looks like you want the list sorted except that you skipped index 4 for some reason which you have not explained. Seems we need to know the exact rules for your logic for assigning an index to a value because we cannot see the logic to it.

Comment: maybe it's a Fibonacci series? :)

Comment: Just giving us another example doesn't help - please explain the logic you are using to come up with the examples. For example, what if in your last example there was an entry for 3000 also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the values except `0` reminds me a geometric sequence with `a0 = 500` and `q = 2`

```
a0 = 500
a1 = a0 * 2 = 1000
a2 = a1 * 2 = 2000
a3 = a2 * 2 = 4000
```

Hence, I'd suggest treating a zero differently (just return `1_0`) and for others:

```
var get = [500, 1000, 2000, 4000]
var str = ""
get.forEach(function(item){
  console.log((Math.log2(item/500) + 2) + "_" + item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the values and then use for zero the value `250`, divide it by `500` and take the logarithm of `2`. Later add an offset of `2` to the result.

```js
var values = [500, 0, 4000, 1000];

values
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .forEach(a => {
        var x = Math.log2((a || 250) / 500);
        console.log((x + 2) + '_' + a);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output is kinda Log_base_2 (item / 500) + 2
Except a value of 0 would be an error not 1, but if you catch the log(0) error and force it to have a value of -1 it would kinda work.
I'm on mobile so give me a min to type out the relevant js.
Edit: @IgorD has a very good answer so following his js would be better than my mobile phone typing could possibly be.